# Host.ResolvePath and relative paths

Tags: t4

I have put my t4 template in a CodeTemplate\MyTemplateFolder folder but can't get it to work from there.

The problem is that I need to access a folder, called models, that is in the root of the project.

Ie:

```
Project Root Folder\CodeTemplates\MyTemplateFolder\MyTemplate.tt
```

and I need to access a file in:

```
Project Root Folder\Models
```

However, I can't figure out how to use `this.Host.ResolvePath` to get at the `Models` folder from my template.

Any suggestions?

Use of:

```
var relativePathModelsFolder = @"..\..\Models";
var path = this.Host.ResolvePath(relativePathModelsFolder);
```

gives me the absolute path to the root folder with ....\Models stuck on the end.

I don't seem to be able to traverse back up to the root, and then into my Models folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solve the issue by getting the project then getting the path then adding the folder:

Getting the project:

```
Project GetLibraryProject(string tier)
    {
        return VisualStudioHelper.GetAllProjects().Where(x => x.Name == tier).First();
    }
```

Getting the path:

```
string GetProjectPath(Project project)
{
    var pathProjectFile = project.FullName;
    return pathProjectFile.Replace(project.Name + ".csproj", "");
}
```

Putting it all together:

```
var project = GetLibraryProject("MyMvcApp.MyClassLibrary");
var path = GetProjectPath(project);
var myUsefulPath = path + @"MyFolderParent\MyFolder";
```

Answer (score 13):

This seems a simpler way to me:

```
({
<#
var projectPath = Host.ResolveAssemblyReference("$(ProjectDir)");
var viewPath = projectPath + "Views";

#>
   view:"<#=viewPath #>",
}
)
```